# How can I add my own handwriting to machine learning "handwriting detection" program (using MNIST data collection and kersa)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I first changed the image size using cv2.resize to 28x28 and I also inverted the colors so that the handwritten image looks just like the MNIST data.

```py
#Converting input image
import cv2
path = r'theImage_1.png' #Creates the string path for the image
img = cv2.imread(path) #cv2 reads the image for the given path
twentyEight = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR) #resizes image to the required 28x28 pixels used by the neural network program
image = cv2.bitwise_not(twentyEight)
```

But when I come to actually use the image in the program using this code:

```py
y_pred = model.predict(image)
y_pred_classes = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
y_sample_pred_class = y_pred_classes[0]
plt.title("Predicted: ", y_sample_pred_class, fontsize=16)
plt.imshow(image.reshape(28, 28), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

It gives me this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected 
shape=(None, 784), found shape=(None, 84)
```

Here is the full code:

```py
#Libraries to import:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.datasets import mnist
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
np.random.seed(0)

#Converting input image
import cv2
path = r'theImage_1.png' #Creates the string path for the image
img = cv2.imread(path) #cv2 reads the image for the given path
twentyEight = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR) #resizes image to the required 28x28 pixels used by the neural network program
image = cv2.bitwise_not(twentyEight)


#Downloading data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data() #Loads the MNIST data into the values

#Categorizing data:
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10) #Changes training data from linear values to values in a grid
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10) #Try to print y_train[0] to get a better idea of what is meant

#Normalizing
x_train = x_train/255 #converts the values of shaded areas from 0-255 to 0-1 (required by the neural program)
x_test = x_test/255
image = image/255

#Reshaping
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], -1) #Changes the dimensions from 28x28 to 728 (1-dimension -> 28x28 = 728)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], -1) #Print(x_test.shape) to get a better idea
image = image.reshape(image.shape[0], -1)

#The neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=128, input_shape=(784,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Training
model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=512, epochs=10)

#Example
y_pred = model.predict(image)
y_pred_classes = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
y_sample_pred_class = y_pred_classes[0]
plt.title("Predicted: ", y_sample_pred_class, fontsize=16)
plt.imshow(image.reshape(28, 28), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you print the shape of `image `? plus i thought, one has to predict in batches, in this case `(1, 784)`?

Comment: Printing the shape of image gives me (250, 399) for some reason, even though at the beginning I resize it to 28x28

Comment: is it related to `,interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR`? what is the shape if you remove this option?

Comment: The image size works when I add "IMREAD_UNCHANGED" to cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHAGED)
But now I need to turn the image into a flat/1-dimenstional image that is (none, 784), which I tried doing using "image = image.reshape(image.shape[0], -1)" but that did nothing

Comment: if the image is `(28, 28)` now, you can use [numpy.flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above error, you may need to change the dimensions of the new predicting image from 28x28 to 728 (1-dimension -> 28x28 = 728) as below:

Please check this fixed code:

```
image = image.reshape(image.shape[-1], -1)

#Example
y_pred = model.predict(image)
y_pred_classes = np.argmax(y_pred,axis=1)
y_sample_pred_class = y_pred_classes[0]

plt.title("Predicted:{}".format(y_sample_pred_class), fontsize=16)
plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

[image]